# Packaging one or two plugins as a standalone RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a handful of Eclipse plugins that I maintain. They are proving useful enough that non Eclipse users have asked for them without the overhead of a full eclipse install.

I am certain this *is* possible, but uncertain how to *make* this possible. My attempts at creating a standalone RCP app and then including my plugins as dependencies have given me mixed results. More specifically, my perspective tries to instantiate a view from a plugin and fails (silently)...

```
public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
layout.addStandaloneView( "myPlugin.ID",  false, IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f, editorArea);
}
```

... but as the same plugin implements a search extension, it *does* show up in the standard Eclipse search dialog.

Are there any resources that hardened Eclipse tars can point me to, that will help overcome this hurdle?

M.

Answer (score 1):

One lead to follow is the notion of **[product build](http://aniefer.blogspot.com/2009/03/building-p2-rcp-products-in-eclipse.html)**, based on [Equinox/p2/Adding Self-Update to an RCP Application](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Adding_Self-Update_to_an_RCP_Application).

[image: Install New Software menu]

Answer (score 1):

What i did is to make the plugin project to dependent on org.eclipse.ui.ide.application and a few other core eclipse plugins. And then I create a new product configuration, make org.eclipse.ui.workbench as the application. I can also define my own icons, splash to do some branding. Then i can export the product to be a stand alone application with my plugin in it.